# checking camera permission if it is granted but I keep getting errors

Tags: flutter, dart, permissions, camera

Trying to develop an App for the first time using DART/Flutter, my app deals with live video streaming, but when I get on checking the camera Permisiion if it is granted I get errors like "Expected to find ';'." and Expected an identifier.

Here is the Code I'm working on:

```
void _onNewCameraSelected(CameraDescription cameraDescription) async {
    // TODO (2): Initialize a new camera
    setState(() {
        _isCameraInitialized = false;
    });

    final previousCameraController = _controller;

    final CameraController cameraController = CameraController(
        cameraDescription,
        ResolutionPreset.high,
        enableAudio: true,
        androidUseOpenGL: true,
    );

    await previousCameraController?.dispose();

    if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
            _controller = cameraController;
        });
    }

    _controller!.addListener(() {
        _isStreaming = _controller!.value.isStreamingVideoRtmp;
        _isCameraInitialized = _controller!.value.isInitialized;

        if (_isStreaming) {
            _startTimer();
            Wakelock.enable();
        } else {
            _stopTimer();
            Wakelock.disable();
        }

        if (mounted) setState(() {});
    });

    try {
        await cameraController.initialize();
    } on CameraException catch (e) {
        log('Error initializing camera: $e');
    }

    _isCameraPermissionGranted
        ? _isCameraInitialized
        ? ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
            child: AspectRatio(
                aspectRatio: _controller!.value.aspectRatio,
                child: CameraPreview(_controller!),
            ),
        )
}
```